# Whats wrong here

Tags: jquery, html

I cannot get this function to fire off... I'm thinking I need a fresh set of eyes to look it over. Can someone tell me where the flaw is? Thank You in advance...

Jquery/javascript

```
function removeAsFriend(a, b, rn) {
    $("#remove_friend_loader").show();
    $("#remove_friend_loader"+a).show();
    $.post("churchScripts/request_join_church.php", { request: "removeFriendship", mem1: a, mem2: b, thisWipit: rn }, function(data) {
        if(<?php echo $admin_id ?> != a){
            window.location.replace("profile.php?id="a);
    }else{
            $("#remove_friend_loader"+a).hide();
            $("#deleteMember"+a).remove();
            $(".mem"+a).remove();
        }
    }); 
}
```

HTML inside a php variable

```
<div class="interactContainers" id="remove_friend">
            <div style="float:right;"><a href="#" onclick="toggleInteractContainers(\'remove_friend\');">cancel</a> </div>
            Remove '.$church_name.' from your church list? &nbsp;
            <a href="#" onclick="removeAsFriend('.$logOptions_id.', '.$id.', '.$thisRandNum.');">Yes</a>
            <span id="remove_friend_loader"><img src="images/loading.gif" width="28" height="10" alt="Loading" /></span>
        </div>
```

Any ideas

**EDIT**

Clarification on the issue... This Jquery function will not run onclick of the yes link

Comment: You forgot to explain what's the issue. "Doesn't work" isn't an explanation

Comment: @zerkms the function simply wont run upon click of the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, but I just found the issue... I missed the + sign at the window.location which caused a syntax error. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Should your anchor tag be like this?

```
<a href="#" onclick="removeAsFriend('".$logOptions_id."', '".$id."', '".$thisRandNum."');">Yes</a>
```

Comment: Yes, all numbers, there is no need to make them a string, and besides that I actually already tried this. still no go!

Answer (score 1):

apply some break points and check whether the function is getting called , or up to what extend is it running

http://asymptomatic.net/2007/08/22/2643/debugging-javascript-in-firefox-with-firebug-and-breakpoints

Some suggestions would be:

1. i think you are echoing the html as a string in php, so go take browser source and check whether the function call appears fine there.
2. edit the function content and replace it with some simple statements like alert(1); and check if the function is getting called.
3. now repace the old function content and add the alert(1); codes a different points of the eunction like:

   ```
   function removeAsFriend(a, b, rn) {
   alert(1);
   -------
   somecode
   -------
   alert(1);
   -------
   somecode
   -------
   alert(1);

   }
   ```

and check how many alerts you got . this way you can fix the point of error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just checked the console error, and it said that removeAsFriend is undefined... Any ideas

Comment: i believe you have put this in the head section with proper script tags. remove the function content and arguments and put a simple alert inside and check if its working while you call. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I just found the issue... I missed the + sign at the window.location which caused a syntax error. Thanks